In docstring, how to give multiple parameters the same description (using EpyText tags)?
For IDEs where hovering over a function call displays help (e.g. PyCharm), rather than create multiple lines with the same description for multiple parameters ... is there a way to simplify by tagging multiple parameters to use the same description?
So instead of this (using EpyText tags) ...
def myfunc(a, b, c, d):
    """
    @param a: integer along the "a" dimension.  
    @param b: integer along the "b" dimension.  
    @param c: integer along the "c" dimension.  
    @param d: integer along the "d" dimension.
    """
    pass

... would like something like this (which doesn't render) ...
def myfunc(a, b, c, d):
    """
    @param a,b,c,d: integer along the corresponding dimension.  
    """
    pass

In the ideal solution not only would there be efficiency of code but also of display (in the rendered help balloon).  That is, all parameters sharing a description would also be listed on the same line (of the balloon text) and have the shared description shown only once.
Alternatives to EpyText can be considered as well.

Epytext doesn't support that, but the NumPy style supports grouping parameters with the same type and description:
def myfunc(a, b, c, d):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    a, b, c, d : int
        Integer along the corresponding dimension.
    """
    pass


That's helpful. Thx.  It simplifies the code.  However, it does not simplify the display.  Upon hovering over the function name, the help balloon expands each parameter into its own line and the description is repeated for each.

@MCornejo Unfortunately, it is up to the IDE to decide how to render a certain style. You might want to open an issue in the YouTrack (but I doubt it would get any attention)
